# Eagle not autorouting custom footprint

Tags: eaglecad, autorouter

I am making a custom footprint for a component. However if I use the component then Eagle doesn't auto route any connections to that component. Does anyone have any ideas?

[image]

Comment: More information needed.  When you created the package did you use proper pads and name them?  When you created the device did you link these to the corresponding pins on the symbol?  Does ratsnest work properly and highlight missing connections if you manually route?

Comment: I didnt use any pads. It is an ic. So I used a top copper layer and a tplace on top of it much like the tqfp 44 example in atmel.lbr. Rats nest works correctly

Comment: Enable 'show grid' and check whether there are grid points on your pads. If not, the autorouter can't reach them. Solution: select a finer grid.

Comment: I will try that out.

Comment: I just tried it. It still doesnt work

Comment: Its the routing grid which I have to change. It works now

Answer (score 2):

Enable 'show grid' and check whether there are grid points on your pads. If not, the autorouter can't reach them. Solution: select a finer (routing!) grid.

Comment: I don't think the grid points on the board drawing matter, just the grid size you define in the autoroute menu.

Comment: Yes, the OP discovered that it was the routing grid and not the drawing grid that was the problem. Unfortunately, the question still appears as though it has not been successfully answered.

Answer (score 0):

I'm willing to bet that you put the outline for the component into the Dimension layer, which is really only for the board outline.  Put it in the tDoc layer, or something like that.

I did the exact same thing, once upon a time, and it was very frustrating.

Comment: It was the routing grid...see the full list of comments to the original question.

Comment: thx Scott Seidman. Had exactly the same problem and putting my parts outline on any other layer as "Outline" solved it.